# Adding UITextView/UILabel on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiscrollview

I am trying to add a `UITextView` on `UIScrollview`. and then add the `UIScrollView` onto a `UIView`. The adding scrollView to `UIView` works however adding `UITextView` to a `UISCrollView` Does not work. Any pointers?

Thanks

```
UIScrollView * contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 400, 250, 250)];
contentScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UITextView * mainContent = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 400, 200, 200)];
mainContent.text = @"HELLO";
mainContent.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[contentScrollView addSubview:mainContent];
[contentScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[contentView addSubview:contentScrollView];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your height of scrol view is 250 and width also 250. but u are giving the frame of textview beyond these limits i.e.  300, and 400. limit them to 250, 250 like

```
UITextView * mainContent = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
```

Comment: Oh so the position of the lable is relative to the UIScrollView? I thought it was relative to the main screen. Anws yes that worked. Thanks :)

Comment: no. it should be relative to the parent/super view for every thing

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code:

```
UIScrollView * contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 270)];
contentScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[contentScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];    

UITextView * mainContent = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 30, 200, 200)];
mainContent.text = @"HELLO";
mainContent.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[contentScrollView addSubview:mainContent];        
[self.view addSubview:contentScrollView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this technique

```
UIScrollView * contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 270)];
```

and add it into your `UIScrollView` like:

```
UITextView * mainContent = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
contentScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[contentScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];    
[contentScrollView addSubview:mainContent];
```